# Objective C use UUID for queue name

Tags: objective-c, uuid

`dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create(%uuid%, NULL);`

What is the incantation required to permit a uuid in the code above?

Thanks!

Comment: There *is no "incantation"*. See [dispatch_queue_create](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_queue_create.3.html) - the argument is `const char* label`. Thus the "incantation" is to get a UUID in such a data-type (i.e. "get a string representing a UUID which can be used as a label"). Don't rely on magical mantras; follow the steps.

Comment: As a newcomer to Obj-C I'm still wrapping my head around many of the concepts. I couldn't understand why `[[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]` wouldn't work. Anyway, the "incantation" (that's what it equates to imo) is below.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *uuid = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
const char *cuuid = [uuid cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_queue_create(cuuid, NULL);
```